# Draw a rectangle figure and 2 additional squares with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to draw the following image with CSS

[image]

I have get this code that helps me with the rectangle.
Here I have the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DiegoTc/Eg53q/).

```
div.bonecard {
    width: 3.4in;
    height: 2.1in;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: .2in;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: .5in;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: .5in;
    -moz-border-radius: .2in;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: .5in;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: .5in;
    border-radius: .2in;
    border-top-right-radius: .5in;
    border-bottom-right-radius: .5in;
}
```

How to draw the additional components?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`

https://jsfiddle.net/Eg53q/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/Eg53q/1/

```
div.bonecard:before, 
div.bonecard:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: -24px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    content: ' ';
}

div.bonecard:after {
    top: 100px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: ' ';
}
```

It means you don't need to add any superfluous HTML to achieve a presentational effect.